# Is an Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC Assigner required when returning a subtype?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Suppose I wish to implement the `Function<Object, Object>` interface by doing something very stupid like this:

```
final ParameterizedType whatTheUserWillSee = functionObjectObject(); // e.g. Function<Object, Object>
DynamicType.Builder<?> builder = builder
  .subclass(Object.class, ConstructorStrategy.Default.NO_CONSTRUCTORS)
      .merge(Visibility.PUBLIC, SyntheticState.SYNTHETIC, TypeManifestation.FINAL)
      .defineConstructor(Visibility.PUBLIC, SyntheticState.SYNTHETIC)
      .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(OBJECT_CONSTRUCTOR).onSuper()) // OBJECT_CONSTRUCTOR is just new Object()
      .implement(whatTheUserWillSee)
      .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(new MethodDescription.ForLoadedMethod(Object.class.getMethod("toString"))
                 .withAssigner(Assigner.DEFAULT, Assigner.Typing.DYNAMIC));
```

That is, I'm creating something like this:

```
public Foo() {
  super();
}
public Object apply(Object x) {
  return toString();
}
```

*Without* the `.withAssigner` invocation, I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot return class java.lang.String from public java.util.function.Function java.util.function.Function.compose(java.util.function.Function)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodCall$TerminationHandler$Simple$1.toStackManipulation(MethodCall.java:3005)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodCall$Appender.toStackManipulation(MethodCall.java:3551)
    at net.bytebuddy.implementation.MethodCall$Appender.apply(MethodCall.java:3509)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyCode(TypeWriter.java:708)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod$WithBody.applyBody(TypeWriter.java:693)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$MethodPool$Record$ForDefinedMethod.apply(TypeWriter.java:600)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default$ForCreation.create(TypeWriter.java:5660)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.TypeWriter$Default.make(TypeWriter.java:2166)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:232)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:204)
    at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase.make(DynamicType.java:3595)
```

I am not an expert in the internals of ByteBuddy.  Why is a dynamic type assigner necessary in order to return a subtype of `Object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are intercepting all methods of `Function`. While you think that you are intercepting apply, if you look carefully, Byte Buddy is complaining about the `compose` method. Specify an explicit matcher to avoid this.